# Curl lets me GET but does not let me POST ... Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, curl, spring-data-jpa

When I run the Spring Application and then try to comunicate with
the REST API it allows me to GET but not to POST.

So this works:

```
curl -u user:a75fd7ea-9a6e-4943-bc0c-3b0a96bda51b http://localhost:5000/activity/getall
```

This does not work:

```
curl -u user:a75fd7ea-9a6e-4943-bc0c-3b0a96bda51b
-H "Accept: application/json" 
-X POST 
-d '{
    "name":"Sleep",
    "criteria":"Sleep at least 8 hrs",
    "ini":"2022-08-30",
    "periodicity":"DAY",
    "periodicityCount":"1"
    }'
http://localhost:5000/activity/post
```

If you notice is the same Username and Password.

This is the response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 29 Aug 2022 19:25:27 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "timestamp": "2022-08-29T19:25:27.510+00:00",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "path": "/activity/post"
}
```

Comment: Did you enable csrf protection in your application?

Comment: @g00glen00b yes and that was the problem, I disabled it and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your API calls fail is due to the CSRF protection you enabled in your Spring Security configuration.

The way this works is that for each non-GET request (= POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE), you need to include a CSRF token.

To obtain a CSRF token, you first need to fire a GET request (eg. `http://localhost:5000/activity/getall`). In the response headers, you should see a `Set-Cookie` header containing an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie. For example:

```
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=098b732a-282a-11ed-a261-0242ac120002
```

Now you need to copy the value of the `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie (should contain a UUID), and set it as the value of the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header:

```
curl \
-u user:a75fd7ea-9a6e-4943-bc0c-3b0a96bda51b
-H "Accept: application/json"
-H "X-XSRF-TOKEN: 098b732a-282a-11ed-a261-0242ac120002"
-X POST \
-d '{
    "name":"Sleep",
    "criteria":"Sleep at least 8 hrs",
    "ini":"2022-08-30",
    "periodicity":"DAY",
    "periodicityCount":"1"
    }'
http://localhost:5000/activity/post
```

After that, your request should succeed. Be aware, the response of this POST-request will contain a new CSRF token that you will have to copy to your next request.

Alternatively, you can disable CSRF protection by setting `.csrf().disable()` in your Spring Security configuration.

Comment: Just a question, what is the purpose of csrf?  I mean, why do they want to make sure you do a GET request first?    What if you just need to POST?   isnt that a waste of time and/or resouces?

Comment: @ErnestoOrozco Let's say your webapp is popular and I build a malicious website that sends a DELETE-call to your API. If someone visites that website and uses your webapp, then the call will succeed if you rely on cookies for authentication. With CSRF, the malicious website has to read the CSRF-header (it can't) and pass it as a cookie (it can't do that either), so the malicious website can't forge those API calls.